# Do BeanFactoryPostProcessors affect BeanPostProcessors?

Tags: java, spring

If a `BeanPostProcessor` or its dependency is annotated with `@Value`, would that work?

```java
@Component
@Slf4j
public class Sage {
    @Wisdom
    private String wisdom;

    public void sayWisdom() {
        String processedWisdom = process(wisdom);
        log.info(processedWisdom);
    }

    private String process(String wisdom) {
        String intro = getIntro();
        String wiserWisdom = makeItSoundWiser(wisdom);
        return intro + " " + wiserWisdom;
    }

    private String getIntro() {
        return "Sage says:";
    }

    private String makeItSoundWiser(String wisdom) {
        return wisdom.replaceAll("\\.(?=\\s|$)|(?<!\\.)(?=$)", "...");
    }
}
```

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Wisdom {
}
```

```java
public interface WisdomProvider {
    String getWisdom();
}
```

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WisdomBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
    private final WisdomProvider wisdomProvider;
    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        Field[] fields = bean.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            Wisdom wisdom = field.getAnnotation(Wisdom.class);
            if (Objects.nonNull(wisdom)) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                ReflectionUtils.setField(field, bean, wisdomProvider.getWisdom());
                break;
            }
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class SimpleWisdomProvider implements WisdomProvider {
    @Value("#{'${wisdoms}'.split(',')}") // notice this
    private String[] wisdoms;

    @Override
    public String getWisdom() {
        int randomIndex = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(wisdoms.length);
        return wisdoms[randomIndex];
    }
}
```

```
wisdoms=Tomorrow is often the busiest day of the week,\
        I have always wanted to be somebody, but I see now I should have been more specific,\
        Knowledge is like underwear. It is useful to have it, but not necessary to show it off,\
        Go to Heaven for the climate, Hell for the company,\
        Going to church doesn't make you a Christian any more than going to a garage makes you an automobile
```

The answer it no, it won't work

```
INFO  [main] : Sage says: ${wisdoms}...
```

The question I have is why? `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`s (including `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` that processes `@Value`s) should run fine on `BeanPostProcessor`s' `BeanDefinition`s. Unless `BeanPostProcessor`s don't get created from `BeanDefinition`s... What is the explanation? What is the workaround?

Comment: You have a chicken/egg problem here, you want to use a `BeanPostProcessor` but you also want to inject beans, that need processing into the `BeanPostProcessor`. Also you should just use `@Value("${wisdom}")` Spring will the conversion to an array. I wonder how you are running this and what the logging output actually is.

Comment: The problem is also enhanced by the fact that `BeanPostProcessor` instances are created very early in the whole proces. Autowiring has to be done very carefully and when doing so you might get beans that are fully processed yet due to the moment in the lifecycle.

Comment: @M.Deinum are `BeanPostProcessor`s created from `BeanDefintion`s? Are those `BeanDefinition`s processed by `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`s (such as `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`)?

Comment: As stated yes but... As they are created very early in the process not everything applies. Also as they are very early you trigger very early instantiation of the beans it needs which are then no longer being processed. When adding Spring Boot in the mix (which I suspect is the case) things change slightly again, but not in regards of processing.

Comment: @M.Deinum you were mistaken, it can work (see the answer)

Comment: No I'm not mistaken as you still have a chicken/egg problem with the `BeanPostProcessor`, however Spirng will do its best to prevent it but cannot in all cases. Both the `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` and `BeanPostProcessor` are needed very early on (the `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` very early as that operates on bean definitions and not beans).

Comment: @M.Deinum what exactly may be the problem? Notice it's `static`. First, a BeanFactoryPostProcessor is created, it processes a `BeanDefinition` of my `BeanPostProcessor`, then the latter gets created from that modified `BeanDefinition` and does its job. I don't see any problems at all

Comment: Not in this particulair case but in general (as also explained/referenced/hinted) in the actual Spring documentation. Especially with regards to proxy creation (which isn't the case here) and injection into a `BeanPostProcessor` as proxy creation is also done through a `BeanPostProcessor` and that might not be ready. So injection into a `BeanPostProcessor` might lead to surprising results.

Comment: @M.Deinum even when those injections are `@Lazy`?

Comment: That depends on the usage but that is one of the likely workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it can work, but you need to register that `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` that processes `@Value` annotations in the context if it's a non-Boot project

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```